# Why do these meta tags not work?

Tags: html, meta-tags

I have these meta tags in the `<head>` of my webpage, but when i try to save the page to my homepage, it doesn't show my icon or turn into a web app (it opens in safari automatically)

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="http://bithumor.co/bh-icon.png">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="white">
```

Here's the code to my entire page (if you would like to see it to help answer my question) - http://pastebin.com/y7DTJfdm

Comment: Well one thing I can tell right off is you have no document declaration, content above your `<html>` tag, and you haven't closed your `<head>` tag. In any case, the rendered HTML code is what's interesting to debug. Try to validate your html and you'll see it won't be even close to being valid, so I would start with that.